# LiteDB en UWP abrir una base de datos en modo share

Tags: c#

Queria saber como puedo abrir la base de datos de LiteDB con la aplicacion de modo compartido para poder ver los cambios con una PC ?

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var folderPath = localFolder.Path;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, DBName);
            ConnectionString ConnectionString_DB = new ConnectionString();
            ConnectionString_DB.Filename = filePath;
            ConnectionString_DB.Async = true;
            ConnectionString_DB.Mode = LiteDB.FileMode.Exclusive;

            //Global_DB = new LiteDatabase(filePath);
            Global_DB = new LiteDatabase(ConnectionString_DB);

            LineasReporteDB = Global_DB.GetCollection<LineaReporte>("LineasReporte");//prepara la coleccion para las lineas
```

este ejemplo esta hecho en UWP y lo que quiero hacer es poder habrir el archivo de la base de datos con el programa en la pc en solo lectura, pero el archivo esta look! en la pagina de LiteDB dice que puedo habrirlo en mo Shared pero esta posibilidad no esta disponible.

Comment: Podrias compartir el codigo que tienes a modo de que la pregunta tenga un [mcve]

Comment: Modifique la pregunta y agregue codigo en ella

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta linea

```
ConnectionString_DB.Mode = LiteDB.FileMode.Exclusive;
```

por esta

```
ConnectionString_DB.Mode = LiteDB.FileMode.Shared;
```

Eso hará que la base de datos se abra en modo shared.

EDIT:

Prueba a  usar `SharedLocalFolder` en vez de `LocalFolder` y asegurate de que tengas los permisos necesarios.

Todo lo guardado en LocalFolder es para uso personal de la aplicacion no se para que querrias compartirlo.

Comment: Ese es el problema no esta disponible el modo Shared!

Comment: Al parecer es en UWP que no esta disponible esta posibilidad!